# How do I efficiently install truffle and ganache-cli in a docker container?

Tags: truffle, ganache, ganache-cli, docker

Say I want to run a container with `ganache-cli` and `truffle` globally installed for dev purposes.

I have this first attempt Dockerfile

```yaml
FROM node:15-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY . .

RUN apk add -t .gyp --no-cache git python g++ make &&\
    npm install -g truffle ganache-cli &&\
    npm install &&\
    apk del .gyp

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sh" ]
CMD [ "./entry.sh" ]
```

which executes `entry.sh` at start:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ganache-cli -m "test test test test test test test test test test test junk" -h 0.0.0.0 --secure &

sleep 2

truffle migrate --network develop

wait
```

and this works, for sure; but I want to make the process of building the image as fast as possible. Do someone knows how can I improve this Dockerfile?

**UPDATE**: I am installing this Docker image within a container. There is no cache between builds because a new container is created everytime. This is know as Docker-in-Docker.

Comment: have you looked at this https://devopsprodigy.com/blog/6-ways-to-build-docker-images-faster/

Comment: I would suggest switching the COPY and RUN command. RUN will install the packages and that layer will remain most of the time the same unless the packages are updated. The code you are copying into the container might change more often and the layer will change.

Comment: I think I can help you. Give me some time.

Answer (score 1):

For the docker bit, I believe the `COPY` and `RUN` commands being interchanged as [Donut](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/8763/donut) mentioned in the comments could help. Reference for this and backing of the claim: [Semaphore Article explaining the layer caching](https://docs.semaphoreci.com/ci-cd-environment/docker-layer-caching/#:%7E:text=workflows%20on%20Semaphore.-,About%20Layer%20Caching%20in%20Docker,the%20execution%20of%20the%20command.). But Since you are using a docker in docker type build this is unlikely to be much.

For the Ethereum dev tools themselves, I believe this is as fast(as few modules packaged together) as possible from looking at the docs.

For the actual installation of tools, possibly consider using `yarn install` or `pnpm install`. Touted performance increases are in the range of 80% - 88% faster than npm install.
[image]

---

Excuse this opinion-based answer community.